# Composite index in Mongo DB: saving duplicates

Tags: mongodb, indexing

As per [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/), you can create a `composite index` to facilitate search.

What is unclear for me, would the `composite index` prevent duplicates from being created, and if yes, how to configure such an index?

Comment: Really unclear in what you are asking. I think you need to show your "composite index" definition as well as what you are actually trying to do with some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A compound index can be used to reject duplicates but does not do so by default. If you would like to ensure uniqueness based on a compound key, run db.coll.ensureIndex() to create your index with {'unique': true} passed as an option. See [this page](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.ensureIndex/#options-for-all-index-types) for details.